# How can I download image using Glide lib with volley response

Tags: android, android-volley, android-glide

I'm facing problem with glide image loading, currently I'm using the given code which I searched from stackoverflow, but not working with me,

**Details**:
            is volley response I have string url and below code I'm using but working in my condition, need help

```
@Override
                public void webServiceCompleted(JSONObject responseJson) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();

                    message_model=gson.fromJson(responseJson.toString(),myModelClass.class);
                    String url= message_model.getMessage_image();
                    commonFuntions.mLoaderCancel(mContext);

                    Glide
                            .with(getApplicationContext())
                            .load(url)
                            .into(_ImageView);
                }
```

But after loading the screen remains blank, even I can't using placeholder for it.

Comment: check volley response for image url in logcat.

Comment: i'm getting image url in response

Comment: try to load your image response in a web browser. Because the way you are using Gilde, has no issue in it.

Comment: can you post your image url? Also check this line for the response it returns. ` String url= message_model.getMessage_image();`

Comment: @Charu i check in browser it loads the image but in mobile its not working

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi here is my responce with url, kindly check it and give suggestions
https://i.imgur.com/UD2kOob.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to load your image url is correct, Problem is with the url of the image, append `"http://"` in the beginning of the response url and then try your original code again. It should work.

Answer (score -1):

This is for load imageurl into imageview using glide.

library for glide : compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Stringurl)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(yourimageview);
```

but first check your response.